# Collision between ball and platform

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, collision-detection

I'm developing a game were i need to detect collision between two objects (a platform and a ball):

```
platform = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 300, 60, 15)];
[platform setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barrinha.png"]];
[platform setCenter:CGPointMake(150, 330)];
[platform setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[pit addSubview:platform];

ball = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 300, 15, 15)];
[ball setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"]];
[pit addSubview:ball];
```

I'm using this code here to detect it:

```
//EDIT FROM HERE
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, platform.frame)){
    pos.y = -pos.y;
}
//TO HERE
```

The problem is that it detects the collision o the TOP and BOTTOM side of the platform but on the sides of it. When there's a SIDE COLLISION the ball gets in the platform and keeps shaking inside until it get out.

**Comment on the EDIT: So as you can see i'm just making it change it's direction. So no I need some help on what would be the better way to find a way to handle the side collisions.**

I already tried to use [Joe Blow's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051921/cocoa-collision-detection-question) but it really works for objects that have the same  width and height.
So i'd like to now if you guys have any ideas to help me out with this issue.

Live long and prosper, dudes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same with two CGRects and it worked nicely. Maybe there is a issue with one of the frames? You could in theory always use `CGRectIntersection(ball, platform)` instead and check the width and height of the resulting rect to be > 0.

Just in case, could you perhaps print out the actual rects before checking for the intersection, that way you get a bit more detail.

EDIT: You need to take both the y and x axis into account, so instead of only flipping one of the pos, flip them both.

Comment: Actually, i got a better look, an the problem isn't the detection but what i do after it's detected. Get a look at the edit up there (:

Comment: You need to describe the problem a bit further, what do you want to happen after the collision? Ball to bounce back? In this case you need to figure out the direction the ball was coming from and work with that instead of simply reversing the y-axis position. For example, if it were to hit at an angle you'd need to find the new angle and adjust the position accordingly.

Comment: Ah, sorry. OK. I need it not to go into the platform and i need it to bounce off in an opposite direction.